# How to parse sed regex syntax?

Tags: sed

```
sed -i "0,/test/s//#test/g" file.txt
```

I do not know how to parse this regex. It is commenting out test by putting #, but my questions are

- what is "0," at the beginning?
- what is it not like "s/test/#test/g" ? aka why is `/s` is in the middle?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For your first bullet point: http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-addr1_002c_002bN

Comment: for the second bullet point: The regex says: from before the beginning (line `0`) until a line containing `test` is found, for each line that matches, replace all occurrences of `test` on that line with `#test` Your suggested replacement applies to all lines in the file that contain `test` - not just the first.   Try it here: https://sed.js.org/?gist=2d0276d43e4aee5fafdc1d19f328b951

Answer (score 0):

Lets break it down into smaller pieces:

https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-script-overview

> sed commands follow this syntax:
>
> ```
> [addr]X[options]
> ```
>
> X is a single-letter sed command. [addr] is an optional line address. If [addr] is specified, the command X will be executed only on the matched lines.

And

https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Range-Addresses

> An address range can be specified by specifying two addresses separated by a comma (,). An address range matches lines starting from where the first address matches, and continues until the second address matches (inclusively)

In the case of `0,/test/s//#test/g` the address part is `0,/test/` because `s` is the command.  An address part of `0,/test/` means the `s` command is only executed on lines inside that range.  If the sed command was `s/test/#test/g` there wouldn't be an address part and the `s` command would be attempted on every line in the file.

https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-addr1_002c_002bN

> A line number of 0 can be used in an address specification like `0,/regexp/` so that sed will try to match regexp in the first input line too. In other words, `0,/regexp/` is similar to `1,/regexp/`, except that if addr2 matches the very first line of input the `0,/regexp/` form will consider it to end the range, whereas the `1,/regexp/` form will match the beginning of its range and hence make the range span up to the second occurrence of the regular expression.
>
> Note that this is the only place where the 0 address makes sense; there is no 0-th line and commands which are given the 0 address in any other way will give an error.

So in `0,/test/s//#test/g`, the address part `0,/test/` runs the `s` command only on the first line that matches `/test/` - even if it is the first line.

https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-empty-regular-expression

> The empty regular expression ‘//’ repeats the last regular expression match (the same holds if the empty regular expression is passed to the s command).

So `0,/test/s//#test/g` is the same as `0,/test/s/test/#test/g` because the empty regular expression matches the one that was used in the address part - but it can be left out because writing the same regex twice just makes the whole command less readable.

In conclusion:

- `s/test/#test/g` does the replacement on every line in the file that contains `test`
- `0,/test/s//#test/g` does the replacement only on the first line in the file that contains `test`